# I need help filling a header with a background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just want a background image that shows the full image and has text in the top right  and a button in the bottom right, that's also responsive. after trying for 3 hours other peoples responses to similar questions I'm now back to where I started.

here is the image I want to use:[Head-Phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkUft.jpg)

I tried using my knowledge of flexbox and it just kept displaying the top right of the image, I tried using other users variants of flexbox and the CSS background image tag eventually I got it to display the full image but it was stuck at 1024px wide with no responsiveness. any help is appreciated I just cant figure this out.

```html
<div class="bg-img">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="Text">
        <h><b>Introducing, Our New Product</b></h>
        <p><i>nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur</i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-now"> <!-- button eventually -->
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are no images in your code. Please update to show what you've tried. This is well-trodden ground but it's not clear what's going wrong for you based on what you've shown.

Comment: Hi, do you mean the full image, that is with no bits cut off? As the aspect ratios of screens differ this means you will see blank bits at top/bottom/sides (depending on aspect ratio of the screen in relation to aspect ratio of your image). If the answer is yes then use contain for background-size.

Comment: it may just be that I don't know how to explain what I'm trying to do, I'm back at this point because I'm not sure where to start. I've used background: radial gradient() in place of what I want to do with the image on previous projects where it fills in the entire header making an extra large header I want that same effect but with the image I have listed above the code. But I don't want the image to stretch or only show part of the image I want the full image and have it be responsive and i want to have header text in the top right and buy now button in bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```css
.bg-img {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkUft.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="Text">
      <h><b>Introducing, Our New Product</b></h>
      <p><i>nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur</i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-now"> <!-- button eventually -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might want to remove the `min-height` property. I've added it to make the image clearer. However, this approach (apart from setting the min-height) makes the background image fully responsive.

Comment: sorry i was away from my computer, when i did this it showed no background image